# dplyr:filter() to grab the rows

Tags: r, dplyr

For the code below, I am able to grab rows with `Species==setosa`.

```
data("iris")
filter_data<-dplyr::filter(iris,"Species" == "setosa")
print(filter_data)
```

or

````
data("iris")
filter_data<-dplyr::filter(iris,"Species" == 1) 
#since by using ```str(iris)```, the data set shows that the the ```Species ```is factor
print(filter_data)
````

However, the results both show:

```
Description:df [0 × 5]
0 rows
```

How can that be?

However, if I try to use

```
data("iris")
filter_data<-dplyr::filter(iris, as.factor(Species) == "setosa")
print(filter_data)
```

```
data("iris")
filter_data<-dplyr::filter(iris,as.numeric(Species) == 1)
print(filter_data)
```

then it works.

What is the main difference? R cannot identify the factor or dummy variables itself?

I am also a little bit confused with the terminology: factor and dummy variables.

For lm or glm, the factor should be converted to the numeric value, so we say dummy variables?

Comment: Change "Species" to Species without quotations

Comment: thanks @ZhiqiangWang can you give some reason for it?

Comment: I'm not good at explaining. As shown in `filter` help, no quotations are needed for variable names on the left side of the equation.

Comment: ok, it does work. thanks

Comment: No quotations are need due to data masking in dplyr.  Further reading about data masking [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_data_masking.html).

Comment: thanks @tacoman you are brilliant and helpful :P

Comment: @ZhiqiangWang btw, I think Species is not a variable, but one column of the variable dataset

Comment: @MathildaFang, `"Species" == "setosa"` is like matching two unequal strings, which are evidently not equal.  So you are filtering a df with vector having only `FALSE` in it.  Thus, no rows were returned.  To match contents of object `Species` you have to remove its quotation marks and then R will recognise it an object and not a string.

Comment: make perfect sense @AnilGoyal such an excellent explanation :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"Species" == "setosa"` is like matching two unequal strings, which are evidently not equal.

So you are filtering a df with vector having only `FALSE` in it.  Thus, no rows were returned. For filtering any dataframe in `dplyr` we indeed require a logical vector equal to the length of rows in that dataframe.  Wherever, there is a TRUE that row is returned.

you are actually doing something like this

```
filter(iris, 'something' == 'something else')
[1] Sepal.Length Sepal.Width  Petal.Length Petal.Width  Species     
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

If instead you'll do something like this, all rows will be returned.

```
filter(iris, 'a' == 'a')

#check
str(filter(iris, 'a' == 'a'))
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

To match contents of object `Species` you have to remove its quotation marks and then R will recognise it an object and not a string.

Moreover, in dplyr/tidyverse objects are always `attach`ed and thus we do not have to use `$`

Comment: Yes. I think I got confused with the R basic syntax, usually we use ```dateset[, "Species"] to grab the columns, so I always add quotation marks. thank u @AnilGoyal

Answer (score 1):

There are certain rules which are followed by every language and/or package. When using `dplyr`, it is expected that bare column names i.e column names without quotes are passed to the data.

```
dplyr::filter(iris, Species == "setosa")
```

Notice how we are using `Species` and not `"Species"`. There are some other set of rules which are applied when you pass column names as string.

For example, you can use `.data` and then use `"Species"`.

```
dplyr::filter(iris, .data[["Species"]] == "setosa")
```